# Как удалить файл с Диска Google, используя Google Drive Android API?

Tags: android, java, google-drive

Сохраняю файл БД на Google Drive. Использую как пример гугловский проект android-quickstart. Возникла проблем с удалением. 
Может кто-то смог удалить файл? 
Или хотя бы перезаписать файл

Comment: @Мария_1, напишите, пожалуйста, в чем именно проблема проявляется.

Comment: @Fike проблема в том, что я не знаю вообще как организовать удаление. Везде есть только примеры, где предлагается просто переименовать файлы, но из-за этого будет много мусора

Comment: По идее файлы в Диске не удаляются. Они просто помечаются `trash()`

Answer (score 1):

С этим не работал, но [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295903/how-to-delete-a-file-on-google-drive-using-google-drive-android-api) что находит в поиске гугол.

```
public void trash(DriveId dId) {
  try {
    String fileID =  dId.getResourceId();
      if (fileID != null)
        _drvSvc.files().trash(fileID).execute();
  } catch (Exception e) {} 
}

public void delete(DriveId dId) {
  try {
    String fileID = dId.getResourceId();
      if (fileID != null)
        _drvSvc.files().delete(fileID).execute();
  } catch (Exception e) {} 
}
```

**ПРАВКА------------**

В целом, как я понял, их API для android не поддерживает удаление. Но их Rest API вполне может это делать (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete). Поэтому предлагаю использовать запросы к rest API. Можно использовать популярные библиотеки типа Retrofit (http://square.github.io/retrofit/) или отправлять запрос самому.

Например с Retrofit это будет выглядеть примерно так:

Создаем интерфейс

```
public interface GoogleDriveService {


@DELETE("/drive/v2/files/{fileId}")
  void deleteFile(@Path("fileId") String fileId);
}
```

Удаляем

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
.setEndpoint("https://www.googleapis.com")
.build();


GoogleDriveService service = restAdapter.create(GoogleDriveService.class);
service.deleteFile(file_id);
```

Как-то так будет работать. Только перед этим нужно будет авторизироваться.

Comment: @Deadkenny мне нужно для Android. А это все для десктопных приложений

Comment: @Мария_1 в SDK мэнеджере скачайте Google Play services. Далее в sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\ вы найдете примеры работы с Google Drive. Именно на android. И я думаю, что приведенный пример подойдет :)

Comment: @Deadkenny Примеры гляну)А приведенный не подойдет, потому что для него даже надо доп библиотеки, соответственно в google_play_services этого нет)

Comment: @Мария_1 Ну вообще-то есть :) http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/package-summary.html

Comment: @Deadkenny в приведенной вами ссылке есть следующее:
    _drvSvc = new com.google.api.services.drive.
А это другие библиотечки.. десктопные..

Comment: @Мария_1 ну ок, ваша взяла. Для андройда пользуйтесь com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive

Comment: @Deadkenny Пользуюсь.. мне бы удалить файлик)

Comment: @Мария_1 выше написал добавление к посту. В SDK для андройда видимо пока еще удаление не реализовали. Из-за философских причин наверное.

Answer (score 0):

Вот кидаю вам процедуру из своего рабочего проекта.

```
public void Update(DriveId dId) {
    try {
        DriveFile sumFile = dId.asDriveFile();
        com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status deleteStatus =
                sumFile.delete(CloudMenu.mGoogleApiClient).await();
        if (!deleteStatus.isSuccess()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to delete app data.");

        } else {
            // Remove stored DriveId.
          //  preferences_driverId.edit().remove("drive_id").apply();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```